# Passing a single variable as a std::initializer_list as a function parameter

Tags: c++, c++11, initializer-list

I noticed something odd when changing some existing code to take `std::initializer_list`'s as function parameters.  This was the original code:

```
function(type_t<t> parameter)
```

And this is what I changed only the function declaration to:

```
function(std::initializer_list<type_t<t>> parameter)
```

I then compiled my code to get a list of errors of what I need to change because of the modification.  I was surprised when there were none.  I also ran my program and it behaved just as before.  Is proper use and intended behavior of a `std::initializer_list`?

Edit:
Here is the actual code in question.  Function definition:

```
bool Coaxial(const std::initializer_list<Vector2<t>> _l) const
{
    bool result_x = 1;
    bool result_y = 1;

    for(Vector2<t> other : _l)
    {
        if(other.x() != x())
            result_x = 0;
    }

    for(Vector2<t> other : _l)
    {
        if(other.x() != x())
            result_x = 0;
    }

    return (result_x || result_y);
};
```

And where it is called:

```
static std::vector<AxisAligned_Rectangle2<t> > Construct(std::vector<Vector2<t> > _set)
{
    std::vector<AxisAligned_Rectangle2<t> > result;

    if(_set.size() == 2)
    {
        if(!_set[0].Coaxial(_set[1]))
        {
            if(std::abs(_set[0].x()) <= std::abs(_set[1].x()) && std::abs(_set[0].y()) <= std::abs(_set[1].y()))
            {
                result.push_back(AxisAligned_Rectangle2<t>(_set[0], _set[1].x() - _set[0].x(), _set[1].y() - _set[0].y()));
            }
            else
            {
                result.push_back(AxisAligned_Rectangle2<t>(_set[1], _set[0].x() - _set[1].x(), _set[0].y() - _set[1].y()));
            }
        }
    }
    else if(_set.size())
    {
        bool valid = 1;
        Vector2<t> origin(_set[0]);
        Vector2<t> opposite(_set[0]);

        for(int i=0; i<_set.size(); ++i)
        {
            if(std::abs(_set[i].x()) <= std::abs(origin.x()) && std::abs(_set[i].y()) <= std::abs(origin.y()))
                origin = _set[i];

            if(std::abs(_set[i].x()) >= std::abs(opposite.x()) && std::abs(_set[i].y()) >= std::abs(opposite.y()))
                opposite = _set[i];
        }

        for(int i=0; i<_set.size(); ++i)
        {
            if(!_set[i].Coaxial(origin) && !_set[i].Coaxial(opposite))
                valid = 0;
        }

        if(valid)
            result.push_back(AxisAligned_Rectangle2<t>(origin, opposite.x() - origin.x(), opposite.y() - origin.y()));
    }

    return result;
};
```

The code compiles and it works.  Note that I'm only inputting a vector, not a vector as a single element of an initializer_list.

Comment: It's kind of hard to say, since you haven't said what that code *was*. Or what you intend this change to actually do.

Comment: According to the code, you're passing `Vector2<t>` to the `Coaxial` as `initilizer_list<Vector2<t>>` here: `if(!_set[0].Coaxial(_set[1]))`. This doesn't make sense for me.

Comment: Exactly - that is my question. Is the intializer_list seeing this as normal behavior or is there something else going on?

Comment: Turns out the code wasn't being pulled in by the compiler because the template wasn't being used. This code shouldn't work, and doesn't.

Comment: @ShawnBuckley, Yes, it's expected, normal behavior. `initilizer_list` can be constructed from `brace-enclosed list`, but not from one element. I already told that in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
function(type_t<t> parameter)
```

And this:

```
function(std::initializer_list<type_t<t>> parameter)
```

Are not same. Look at the differences in the following code:

```
template <class T>
using type_t = T;

template <class T>
void function_1(type_t<T> /*parameter*/)
{

}

template <class T>
void function_2(std::initializer_list<type_t<T>> /*parameter*/)
{

}

int main()
{
    function_1(42);

    // function_2(42); - incorrect

    function_2({ 42 });
    //         ^-  -^
}
```

You can't just convert `type_t` to `initializer_list`. You have to make *brace-enclosed list* with one element and pass it.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. I'm going to post my actual to code to clear up the ambiguity.

Comment: @ShawnBuckley, OK, I delete my answer for a time.